# Filter records from a database on a minimum time interval for making graph

Tags: mysql, sql, database, filter, nosql

We have a MySQL database table with statistical data that we want to present as a graph, with timestamp used as the x axis. We want to be able to zoom in and out of the graph between resolutions of, say, 1 day and 2 years.

In the zoomed out state, we will not want to get all data from the table, since that would mean to much data being shipped through the servers, and the graph resolution will be good enough with less data anyway.

In MySQL you can make queries that only select e.g. every tenth value and similar, which could be usable in this case. However, the intervals between values stored in the database isn't consistent, two values can be separated by as little as 10 minutes and as much as 6 hours, possibly more.

So the issue is that it is difficult to calculate a good stepping interval for the query, if we skip every tenth value for some reslution, that may work for series 10 minutes inbetween, but for 6 hour intervals we will throw away too much and the graph will end up having a too low resolution for comfort.

My impression is that MySQL isn't able to have a stepping interval depend on time so it would skip rows that are e.g. in the vicinity of five minutes of am included rows.

One solution could be to set 6 hours as a minimal resolution requirement for the graph, so we don't throw away values unless 6 hours is represented by a sufficiently small distance in the graph. I fear that this may result in too much data being read and sent through the system if the interval actually is smaller.

Another solution is to have more intelligence in the Java code, reading sets of data iteratively from low resolution and downwards until the data is good enough.

Any ideas for a solution that would enable us to get optimal resolution in one read, without too large result sets being read from the database, while not putting too much load on the database? I'm having wild ideas about installing an intermediate NoSQL component to store the values in, that might support time intervals the way I want - not sure if that actually is an option in the organisation.